# Bootable USB not recognizing after restart

Tags: linux, boot, live-usb, bios, chrome-book

I was running a bootable usb of GalliumOs perfectly for the last 1 year on my Chromebook. I had a MicroSD card also plugged in. I was trying to download a file to my USB, when suddenly my computer CPU usage spiked up to 100%. This happens often, so I decided to restart my computer in order to try and fix it. Now, when trying to boot into my computer, the USB is not booting. Instead, I get this error:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...

Boot failed: could not read the boot disk



Booting from floppy...

Boot failed: could not read boot disk
```

Also, when plugging the USB in to another computer, it doesn't seem to recognize that USB.

Comment: USB what? ... USB hard drive? ... USB flash drive?

Comment: It's a USB hard drive that stores all my files.